# Display canonical rewritten URLs and hide dynamic ones

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have tried countless stuff but I can't find a way to display, in the browser URL bar, the rewritten URL instead of the one with the 3 get parameters.

My "ugly" URL :

http://example.com/archive.php?id=tt2131523&date=20131004&title=graceland

The "pretty" URL I need to display :

http://example.com/tt2131523-20131004-graceland.html

Here is my .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /archive.php?id=$1&date=$2&title=$3 [NC,L]
```

My other PHP files serve the "ugly" links, the links work but the URLs remain "ugly". The "prettyfied" version is not displayed.

If I type the "pretty" URL in the browser, the rewriting works and I access the page.

I would like that, even if a user types the "ugly" version, he will be redirected to the "pretty" one.

Do I need to change my links structure (in other php files) and make them directly point to the rewritten version of the URLs or is there a way in .htaccess to display the rewritten version ?

And by the way, are the flags ok ?

Thanks.

Comment: you want to add a rewrite condition that if the URI passes query values then to redirect the page to the "pretty" version **before** then processing the pretty version with the rewrite rule you've provided above. this condition should be a new condition and placed above the rewrite rule you already have.

Comment: Ok, thanks Martin. What would it look like ?

Comment: Is your htaccess in root folder?

Comment: Yes @Starkeen  Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /archive\.php\?id=([^&]+)&date=([^&]+)&title=([^\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2-%3.html? [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^.]+)\.html$ /archive.php?id=$1&date=$2&title=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you @Starkeen . It works ! So, I understand that my RewriteRule was  ok but I didn't have the QSA flag. So, what are your 2 lines doing ? I guess the calling order is important. Can you comment your answer please ?